# How to enable “persistent mode” in Windows failover cluster manager 2012?

Tags: windows, cluster, failover

In Windows Server 2008 R2 there was a checkbox named "Enable persistent mode" on a General tab in the Properties of a cluster resource.

In Windows Server 2012 that seems to have disappeared.

My cluster resource is a "generic script" resource (not that it makes any difference).

How do I enable "persistent mode" for a cluster resource in Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Here has some PowerShell commands to do this, have you seen/tried these at all?

http://blog.crayon.no/blogs/janegil/archive/2011/06/03/enable_2D00_persistent_2D00_mode_2D00_for_2D00_cluster_2D00_resource_2D00_groups_2D00_using_2D00_the_2D00_powershell_2D00_failover_2D00_clustering_2D00_module.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation it seems to me that 2012 either defaults to or is hard-coded to "persistent mode" and they've disabled changing the value with the GUI.